# Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found?

Tags: android, gradle

I am very new in `Android Studio`. I have a problem with `gradle`.
it says,

```
Error:Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found.
Platform SDK does not point to valid `JDK` `(C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_20)`.
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

then what should I do to solve that?

Answer (score 209):

I got this issue in Android studio 4.2 canary, and I had to delete those generated files:

```
.idea/gradle.xml
.idea/workspace.xml
```

then clicking try again to sync the project.

Comment: I deleted the entire .idea  folder and it worked.

Comment: not just in the Canary version, I just updated my work machine (to 4.2.2) that I didn't use for a year that I was on home office and this was the fix

Comment: The solution below is better.

Comment: Please mention wheere the .idea folder is

Comment: @JaiminModi  - in root folder of your project and may be hidden. If you cant find the folder, update the folder view settings in your OS to see hidden folders and files.

Answer (score 123):

Under Android Studio, select `File > Project Structure > JDK location`.
Specify the JDK to the folder of your currently installed JDK. And specify the SDK location as well.

Comment: I had to close and restart Android Studio for this change to take effect.

Comment: I just ran into this problem again after upgrade of AS to 1.5, and wasted another 2 hours trying to solve it. Finally came across my own comment above. To be precise you must select File > Project Structure > JDK location , make the change, click OK and then close and re-open the project before doing anything else. Then the change takes effect.

Comment: As of android studio 4.1, this setting is now in File -> New Project settings -> default settings

Answer (score 84):

Simple solution:

1. Go to build.gradle and at the top there will be a message JDK missing
2. Click on it and use JDK from the list (or download one if you don't have)
3. Sync project

Answer (score 37):

I got this issue in Android Studio 4.2.2, and the solution is very simple, just delete

```
.idea/gradle.xml
.idea/workspace.xml
```

and click on

```
File -> Invalidate Caches/ Restart
```

Comment: It worked, thank you, didn't need to invalidate caches in my case

Answer (score 17):

If you want / need to, update your JDK installation to the version that you want to use.

Next, find the version for your current JDK installation by running `javac -version` or `java -version`.  Check that it is what you expect.

Next, find the JDK installation directory:

- It should be on your %PATH%.
- By default it will be a subdirectory of "C:\Program Files\Java"' for example: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45"

Next, start Android Studio, and go to the "File->Project Structure->JDK Location" preference page.

The file path given by the preference should be the path to the JDK installation director that you identified above.  If it isn't then update it.

Notes:

- Use the full pathname of the installation directory; e.g. "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45".
- Use a pathname, not a URL.

Answer (score 9):

### This Problem occurs when you open your Android Project in Another Computer.

To Solve this,

1. **DELETE** your `.gradle` and `.idea` folder from your project.
2. **`Invalidate Cache and Restart`** Android studio
3. After Restart, **SYNC** Again to automatically create new `.gradle` and `.idea` folders

Answer (score 8):

Just delete `.idea` and `.gradle` folders from your project path on your computer and sync again.

Answer (score 6):

This issue happens if you change the workspace or manually copy files to the new repo workspace. i fixed it by deleting below files,

```
.idea/gradle.xml
.idea/workspace.xml
```

Finally click on File-> invalidate cache and restart

Answer (score 5):

For Android studio **Canary Build Arctic Fox 2020.3.1** this seems like a bug or hard dependency with **Jdk 11**.

I already had jdk defined, but I was still getting this error. Got resolved after installing jdk 11 and providing path to it in the jdk location here

```
File > Project Structure > JDK location
```

Answer (score 5):

I have solve this problem my App name "Addvoicetomusic2";
go to app dir-
C:\Users\amram\AndroidStudioProjects\Addvoicetomusic2

- then remove .gradle and .idea file
  *then connect to internet
- restart android studio project
  successfully solve

Answer (score 3):

If you're working with Android Studio 4.2.2, and you got a zip of somebody's source code, it may often contain the `.idea` folder. Unfortunately, the `.idea` folder may contain gradle SDK configuration, etc., that are only valid for the computer of the person who sent you the source code.

**Solution:**

- Ideally, the sender should have deleted the .idea folder before sending to you, but you can still fix it by ..
- Delete `.idea/gradle.xml` and `.idea/workspace.xml`.

Then do the `gradle sync` again and the error will go away, and it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

For macOS:

1. install JDK from Oracle site
2. Go to the folder:

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
```

Here you will see JDK installed.

Set folder in the Android Studio, something like this:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.1.jdk
```

I don't why it's not possible to automate such tasks after all this years.

Answer (score 1):

amra ram's solution worked for me, more or less. I had an old `.idea` directory with a weird configuration. Deleting it, closing Android Studio, and opening the project again forced it to reinstall and sync Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Android studio settings or preferences and select jdk as shown in image and try syncing project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this same problem, I solved it by specifying the path to the portable (non installed) JDK8.

Answer (score 0):

Same error i got when I install android studio on my pc . at the time of installation I have installed android sdk and android studio in different path so In project structure I have set my new sdk path .
Still I got message of invalid jdk ...then  I knew location of jdk ,again in project structure I have set my jdk path.It works.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem appeared after updating IntelliJ to version 2020.2.1.

Just solved it by going to **Project Structure** -> **SDK**. There I only had the Java jdk. I've added IntelliJ IDEA Platform Plugin SDK and that seems to have solved the problem. gradle loads just fine.

Answer (score 0):

if other answers not work try this
For **Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 15**
File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart
click Invalidate and Restart
it works for me

Answer (score 0):

- First you have to delete the folders - `.idea` and `.gradle` from the source directory.
- Select `File > Project Structure > JDK location`. Specify the JDK to the folder of your currently installed JDK. Ensure that you have installed the JDK version greater than 1.8. Also specify the SDK location.
- Select `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart` click Invalidate and Restart

Answer (score 0):

Just clean and rebuild project worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had to update to the latest Android build, `Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1.` to be specified to make the project compile.

Answer (score 0):

Just deleted the entire .idea folder from your project and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

For me I just did *File -> Invalidate Caches... -> Invalidate And Restart(leave the checkboxes above as default)*
It will take some time but it worked fine .

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the JRE path inside the IDE folder.
Another way is to put JAVA_HOME, configuring in the global variables of windows.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this because I had upgraded Gradle and Java version on one branch and then pulled down a colleague's branch that was still on the old versions.  Fixed it by setting the Java version back.