# Android Studio Gradle issues: Invalid Gradle JDK Configuration found

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle

I am using Android Studio powered by IntelliJ and Gradle, and it is giving me issues. This is the error I get and I really need help. I dont know if my path is correct but I can't seem to fix the problem. Any help will appreciated.

[image]

This is what I get after giving it the location, so I am a bit confused. the location is correct. I admit I don't know what the problem is. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under `Android Studio`, `select File -> Project Structure -> JDK location`.

Specify the `JDK` to the folder of your `JAVA SDK`. And also Make sure the folder does exist.

And take a look at this: **[Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328994/invalid-gradle-jdk-configuration-found)**

Comment: The folder and location was correct, i just went to the oracle website and downloaded 1.8.0_51 and it is working well now. I had 1.8.0_33. Thanks.

Comment: in this IDE, sometimes updating all of the data it need it, can help us. glad to hear that:)

Comment: So basically the idea is to keep updating. It took me 30 mins just thinking what might be wrong. Now i know. Again thanks.