# Invalid Project JDK

Tags: java, android, java-7

I am getting the error and everything is working well, but when I am trying to open emulator, it give the error. I uninstalled and installed many times, I even deleted old folders, but still I cannot fix it. I even tried looking through stack overflow answers, but still it does not work. How can I fix it ?

```
   14:00:22 Invalid Project JDK
             Please choose a valid JDK directory
             Open JDK Settings
    14:00:22 Gradle sync started
    14:00:22 Gradle sync failed: Invalid Project Jdk
```

here my jdk details ;

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77
JDK_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\javaw.exe
```

Please help on this. Thanks for help.

Comment: Not sure of the exact environment you are using but I think you should have JAVA_HOME pointing to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77 and path set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin

Comment: Not sure if that's the casue but shouldn't `JDK_HOME` be set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77`? For now it points at your `JRE`.

Comment: the address in the android jdk local field "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77"

Comment: @nth Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30521215/3967525

Comment: @Soham are you joking with me -_- ? i said i used all answers on the site.. i checked the answer before.. thats why i opened question bro.. -_-"

Comment: @nth A lot of people used to open a same question I guess you know that.And also if you have already visited the link you could have mention that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

i fixed at last after many days.. here maybe it will help who need help on this. I hope it useful who have problem on this..

step 1;

[image]

step 2;

[image]

step 3;

[image]

and click ok again and it will fix automatic.. probably the error gave because of i installed and uninstalled few times.. thank u for ur helps

Comment: Isn't that exactly the solution mentioned in the post pointed out by @Soham in the comments above?