# Cannot open a specific Project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I will try and provide as much information as possible about my problem. This is the situation:

I just did a fresh Arch install; I then installed android-studio from the AUR. The application opens all fine, the problem started when I tried to open an old project I have.

At first I got the following error: `invalid gradle jdk configuration found`.

After a bit of googling I installed the 5 packages for OpenJDK 16 described here (https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Java#Change_default_Java_environment).

This is the output of `javalinux-java status`:

```
[me@frankenstein ~]$ archlinux-java status
Available Java environments:
  java-16-openjdk (default)
```

I kept getting the same error, so following this instructions ([Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328994/invalid-gradle-jdk-configuration-found)) I went into `File > Project Structure > JDK location` in Android Studio and changed whatever was there to: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk`

I then started to get the following error instead:

```
 Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
```

And the Event log in Android Studio also said:

```
9:33 PM Android Studio is using the following JDK location when running Gradle:
                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk
                    Using different JDK locations on different processes might cause Gradle to
                    spawn multiple daemons, for example, by executing Gradle tasks from a terminal
                    while using Android Studio.
```

I went back to `File > Project Structure > JDK location` and changed it back to: `/opt/android-studio/jre`.

For some reason I now get the following (different) error:

```
> Configure project :app
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in /home/daniel/Android/Sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 28 in /home/daniel/Android/Sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 28 not accepted.
Aborting configuration as SDK is missing components in sync mode.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
```

```
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted.
```

```
License for package Android SDK Platform 28 not accepted.
```

```
No variants found for ':app'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists. at:
com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.svs.AndroidModule.deliverModels(AndroidModule.kt:191)
  com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.svs.AndroidExtraModelProvider$Worker.populateBuildModels(AndroidExtraModelProvider.kt:121)
  com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.svs.AndroidExtraModelProvider.populateBuildModels(AndroidExtraModelProvider.kt:81)
  org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:247)
  org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:117)
  org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:77)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.runAction(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:120)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:110)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.buildFinished(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:104)
  jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
  java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
  org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
  org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
  org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:376)
  org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:358)
  org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
  org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:346)
  org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:333)
  org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
  org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
  org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
  org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
  org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
  org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
  org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
  org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
  org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
  com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.buildFinished(Unknown Source)
  org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:179)
  org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:141)
  org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:83)
  org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:75)
  org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
  org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
  org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:75)
  org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:55)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:60)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:58)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
  org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
  org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
  org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
  org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
  org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
  org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:78)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
  org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
  org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
  org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
  java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
  java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
  org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
  java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Some other threads with this error mention that they solved it by going into `Tools > SDK manager`, but I don't have that option in the `Tools` tab. They also mention it can be accessed as:

```
[me@frankenstein ~]$ cd Android/Sdk/tools/bin/
[me@frankenstein bin]$ ./sdkmanager
```

But I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
        ... 5 more
```

At this point I am a bit stuck, and I don't know what else I can do. I am "sure" it is not a problem with my Android Studio/Linux installation because I can create a new project just fine. I just get a problem when I try to open my old project, but I don't know where to look.

I am very new to all this, and I would appreciate any help to get me started with this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share git repo so that i can clone to give it a try.